# VB.NEt crystal reports does not display all data

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

good afternoon!
I created a system for windows that uses crystal reports and the reports on my computer work normally. I have installed the same system on another computer, crystal reports has trouble appending the data, the report has some data and some does not. Anyone know how to solve this, I suspect it's a problem with SAP Crystal Reports records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it sorted out. The report was developed with version 13_0_15 and for the client computer version was installing 13_0_18. So there was incompatibility and it did not show all the data. To solve just installed the version similar to the development version.